# How do you make a “range?” In Lua

Tags: lua

I’m pretty new to scripting or coding and I’m trying to figure out a way to have an input that can be between 1 and 100 without having to write 100 lines of code. I am doing this in Lua and I will include my current lines below.

```
     elseif input.text == '>coins add 100' then coins = coins + 100; print ("coins effected. "..coins)
     elseif input.text == '>coins add 200' then coins = coins + 200; print ("coins effected. "..coins)
     elseif input.text == '>coins add 300' then coins = coins + 300; print ("coins effected. "..coins)
```

I’m using this for a game I’m developing because i thought it would be a good way to practice. This in specific is for a console to change different values for debugging. Tell me if this doesn’t make sense and i will try to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: `string.sub` gets part of a string. `tonumber` converts a string to a number.

Comment: The question does not seem clear; if you want to limit input to a number between 1 and 100, how does that correspond with the example code showing addition with 100, 200, and 300? It isn't clear to me that a clamp as described below is really the answer you seek; if this is user input, asking the user again may be better. What _exactly_ are you trying to do? Provide examples of expected input and desired output. Provide a [mcve] if at all possible. If you can't write some basic code to demonstrate what you want to do, you may need hit the books; SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: @ ex nihilo What I’m trying to do is make it so the user can input any number (say 172) I don’t want to have to add an extra 172 lines of code just for that, I want it all in one spot.

Comment: @Ihappyface00 -- that doesn't really answer my questions. Does the user enter "172", or ">coins add 172", or what? If the user enters "172" what should happen? Should the program tell the user "invalid value, try again," or should the program assume a value of "100"? How does your example code relate to the range 1-100, and how is the input gathered?

Comment: The user would enter “>coins add 172” then the coins value would go up by 172 coins. If they enter a character that isn’t a number like a letter then it will respond with “Not a number”, and the range is as much as they want.

Comment: @ex nihilo Sorry, forgot to @ you in the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that limits a number in a certain range usually called `Clamp`.

```lua
function math.Clamp(val, min, max)
    return math.min(math.max(val, min), max)
end
```

It's basically and literally a `math.max` with `math.min` together.

To avoid 100 `if` statements, I suggest you to make a script to wait for `>coins add` and then ask for a number specifically.

[Edit] Apparently it doesn't allow you to do so, so here is a walkaround:

```lua
local num = string.sub(input.text, 12) -- remove 12 first characters from the string, this will leave a number in it
num = tonumber(num) -- convert a string into Lua number

if not num then -- if the conversion failed, stop the script, print the text
    print("Not a number")
    return 
end

num = math.Clamp(num, 1, 100) -- Limit the number from 1 to 100

coins = coins + num -- add that number
print ("coins effected. " .. coins) -- New amount of coins
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224733/discussion-on-answer-by-spar-how-do-you-make-a-range-in-lua).